# Using 2D float arrays in attribute table fields in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, pyqgis-3, vector-layer

I am currently using QGIS 3.28.0-Firenze for developing custom plugins, using PyQGIS.

I am interested in assigning a table of values to each of the point features of a Vector Point Layer. So then, each feature point would have an attribute called 'MyValuesTable' which would be a 2D float array (or a `m x n` table).

I have been reading the documentation, checking the available widgets in Attributes Form in Layer Properties and read about table joins (table <> layer).

I am also aware of the possibility of populating attribute tables from (Excel/other origins) tables, and performing joins, comparisons or other operations

I have also checked the possibility of setting different values for attributes as a function of different temporal readings.

Any of the alternatives would fit my requirements, unfortunately

For now, I have not been able to find a hint on how to solve the issue, at least from the QGIS UI.

**TL,DR:** Would it be possible to assign a 2d array (table), to a certain attribute in a Vector Point Layer for each feature? I assume that this is programatically possible using PyQGIS, but would it be possible to display this data table for each point in the QGIS UI?

Comment: You can add it as list, but not every data format supports it.

Comment: What kind of displaying, in attribute table or labelling it in map canvas?

Comment: Hi @KadirŞahbaz. I have been checking about using a list widget on an attribute. The option seems to be unavailable for integers, floats and strings. I will investigate which type needed to be able to use the list widget.

Ideally, I would like the table to be displayed on click for each feature in the map view. I am aware that this may not be possible. I would feel comfortable with the table displaying in the docked attribute panel near the map.

I have also checked that JSON structures are possible as widget types if the variable is of type string, I may investigate this.

Thank you

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz Thank you for the edition. I'll keep the formatting style in mind next time